# PHP extract array values with the same key into another array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array as so:

```
    $diff_date_results = 
    Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [differential] => 7.7 [date] => 2012-12-30 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [differential] => 8.2 [date] => 2012-12-31 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [differential] => 9.9 [date] => 2013-01-03 )
    )
```

I would like to extract all values from the differential key of each of the inner arrays to use the array_sum function on the newly created array.

I have this, which draws out the three numbers for me, but I get php errors for each number as an undefined index. (Notice: Undefined index: 7.7 in C:\wamp\www\jquery\test.php on line 55)

My code thus far is as follows:

```
    $diff_results = array();
    foreach($diff_date_results as $entry){
        $diff_results[$entry['differential']];
    }
    print_r($diff_results);
```

I am sure it is simple, I have been screwing around with it for way too long now, any help would be wonderful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$diff_results = array();
foreach($diff_date_results as $entry){
    $diff_results[] = $entry['differential'];
}

//just for displaying all differential
print_r($diff_results);
```

Now, you can use array_sum on $diff_results.

Moreover, if you want to have sum then you can use below method too.

```
$diff_results = "";
foreach($diff_date_results as $entry){
    $diff_results = $diff_results + $entry['differential'];
}

//$diff_results will have sum of all differential
echo $diff_results;
```

Comment: thanks - You helped me out last night too, I really appreciate it. I'll accept the answer in 9 mins.

Comment: I didnt remember, but the only intention/goal here is to learn new things and instruct what i know. Thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$diff_results = array();

foreach($diff_date_results as $key => $entry){
    $diff_results[] .= $entry['differential']];
}

 print_r($diff_results);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `.=` is for strings, not arrays.

Comment: I just tried it and got `Notice: Array to string conversion`.

Comment: I used it all day, yesterday, it worked fine. returned me with an array.

Comment: `$foo = array(); $foo .= "bar"; echo $foo;` prints `Arraybar`.

Comment: you cant just echo an array.

Comment: That also prints `Arraybar`. It's not an array any more, `.=` converts it to a string.

Comment: For clarification, I'm referring to what you had before you edited your answer. Now the `.=` doesn't do anything different from ordinary `=`. There's no need to use `.=` when assigning to `$array[]`, because it's creating a new element and there's nothing to concatenate with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$diff_results = array_map($diff_date_results,
                          function($entry) { return $entry['differential']; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$diff_date_results =    array ( 
        0 => array ( 'differential'=> 7.7, 'date' => 20), 
        1 => Array ( 'differential' => 8.8, 'date' => 20 ), 
        2 => Array ( 'differential' => 9.8 ,'date' => 20 ),
    );
  $value_differential=array();
 foreach( $diff_date_results as $key=>$value){
   print_r($value);
 $value_differential[]=$value['differential'];
 }

 print_r(array_sum($value_differential));
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this question as I have, the best solution in my opinion is a working version of [Barmars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) as below:

```
$diff_results = array_map(function($entry)
                          { 
                          return $entry['differential']; 
                          }, 
                          $diff_date_results);
```

it's a more elegant, 1 line solution (which I've expand to 5 lines for readability).